# set-azjitnetwrokaccesspolicy module not loading in azure automation runbook

Tags: azure-automation

I am creating runbook that will enable Just in time access automatically to all VMs. I imported az.security module from module gallery. But when i try to start run book it gives me error about module cannot load.
Set-AzJITnetworkAccessPolicy : The 'Set-AzJITnetworkAccessPolicy' command was found in the module 'Az.Security', but the module could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module Az.Security'. At line:27 char:1 + Set-AzJITnetworkAccessPolicy -Kind "Basic" -Location "EAST US" -Name ... + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (Set-AzJITnetworkAccessPolicy:String) [], CommandNotFoundException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoloadMatchingModule

Answer (score 0):

From the information provided, seems you are using Azure Automation service in Azure. Whenever you want to execute PowerShell commands in Automation, you need to import modules before implementing them in Runbook. One way to import the module is to traverse to [this link](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az.Security/0.7.8) and click on "Deploy to Azure Automation" button. After clicking, you will be requested for login and then to select azure automation account where you want to import the module.

[image]

For detailed instructions on how to import module, refer [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-runbook-gallery#import-a-module-from-the-module-gallery-with-the-azure-portal).